# Couting 2 different items in c++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to make a game selector that you put in your items and it will spit back out a random item. The final functionality of this program is that you can say how many items you want to be selected. I have the random selector working fine but I can't figure out how to change how many items to select. When I try and run this code it will print out the same item the amount of times selected. I want it to do different items. Here is my code so far:

```
/* Me
6-14-22
Game Selector
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <avector>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int generated;
vector<string> gameList;


bool going = true;
string usrInp = "";
int gamesCount = 0;

int input() {
  
  while(going){
    cout << "Please enter your Items:" << endl;
    getline(cin, usrInp);
    cout << endl;
    if(usrInp == "Done" || usrInp == "done"){
      going = false;
      return 0;
    }  
    gameList.push_back(usrInp);
  
  }
  
}





void pickGame() {
    srand(time(0));
  generated = (rand() % gameList.size());
  cout << endl;
    cout << gameList[generated] << endl;
  
  
}

void gamesNumber(){
  cout << "Please enter the amount of games you want :" << endl;
  cin >> gamesCount;
  int t = 0;
  while(t<=gamesCount){ 
    if(t == gamesCount){
    pickGame();
    t++;
  }
   else{
    t++;
   }
    }
  }
/*
cin gamesCount
pick the amount of games that are in the int of gamesCount
*/


int main() {
  input();
  gamesNumber();
  //gamesNumber();
  //gameList.push_back("Minecraft");
  //gameList.push_back("Film mac up");
  //gameList.push_back("Raft");
  //gameList.push_back("Roblox");
  //gameList.push_back("Forza Horizon 4");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things: First of all you should only call `srand` *once* in your program. And preferably not use it (and `rand`) at all, but instead use [the nice PRNG classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) available in the C++ standard library. Secondly, who taught you to use global variables? Please don't do that, define variables locally, pass arguments when needed, and return values.

Answer (score 0):

Your game picking function looks fine, but the gamesNumber() function is kind of weird.

From what I understood, you want to pick `gamesCount` games. So you just need to call the `pickGame` function `gamesCount` times. Meaning that you can just use a for loop:

```
void gamesNumber(){
  cout << "Please enter the amount of games you want :" << endl;
  cin >> gamesCount;
    for(int i = 0; i < gamesCount; i++) pickGame();
  }
```